# The concept of implementing key/value stores with relational database languages

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, nosql

I want to get myself wet with the concept of implementing key/value stores with relational database languages (like mysql and sql server).

However this is one of the times when Google isn't good enough.

Does anyone know of any good info / good links regarding the concept of implementing key/value stores with relational database languages?

Comment: Exactly, why would you want to do that? Since RDBMS - the important word is _relational_ - are precisely designed to handle cases where key/value doesn't fit?

Comment: probably the same reason why you would want to learn to ride a bicycle. i want to equip myself with the skills to be able to apply the concept of implementing key/value stores on relational dbms systems. And it's not like no one's implementing key/value stores using relational dbms, there are tons of examples of people doing it.. so i'm not asking for something abstract.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126271/key-value-pairs-in-relational-database/127172#127172

Answer (score 0):

Wiki for EAV http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model. SO answer with link to whitepaper called "Best Practices for Semantic Data Modeling for Performance and Scalability" [EAV over SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336449/eav-over-sql-server/1336471#1336471)

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason to do a key value schema implementation in relational is to have the flexibility of a small sub-schema with key value aspects and the main schema being relational or vice versa.   This could give one extreme flexibility to address key value lookups for some portion of the application and others a traditional relational option without having to keep multiple databases. 
In fact we have implemented such cases for some of our customers, where the customers are either a specific relational DB shop or for the same above mentioned reasons.   You can always create a key value store in a relational database but not the other way.